# Touchpad scrolling not working in Asus r558u (Ubuntu 15.10)

Tags: 15.10, touchpad, asus, scrolling

Touchpad scrolling is not working in my Ubuntu 15.10 installed on an Asus R558U. I have installed `gpointing-device` too using `sudo apt-get install gpointing-device-settings`, but its just showing mouse settings as in this screenshot

.[image]

I don't wish to use the mouse to keep scrolling.

Output of `xinput`

```
:~$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN1000:00 04F3:0401                     id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam                     id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

`Output of dmesg | grep pnp` and `dkms status` is empty.
Please ask for any
 command output that might be helpful

Comment: This specific device is not supported by the kernel. Try to boot from a livecd of Ubuntu 16.04. Does it work there? If not, report a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem and same pointing device on Asus X555UB. I can confirm the touchpad working with last live 16.04, so I installed those kernel drivers (4.4.5-040405-generic in my case) on my xubuntu 14.04. No problem arisen so far. 
Here's one of many links describing how to update:
http://www.yourownlinux.com/2016/03/how-to-install-linux-kernel-4-4-5-in-linux.html